# How can I organize movies, with IMDB import and fields for tags?

Tags: windows, video, file-management

How can I organize movies on Windows?

Features wanted:

- IMDB import
- fields: director, genre, year, actors,...
- covers
- manage DVD / BD / ripped AVIs, MKV
- moving/renaming files according fields

I want to achieve something like: `M:\Movies\Director\year. title (genre).avi`
A syntax that lets me choose how I organize my files (like foobar2000 & mp3 files) according IMDB and personal tags would be great.

Auto fetch covers and listing of not-yet-ripped/yet-to-be-seen/wanted/loaned movies (txt, HTML or whatever) would be some nice features too.

Comment: I personally like using the "BENNO" DVD towers from IKEA to organize movies, but what does this have to do with computers? :)

Comment: This should have been community wiki.

Comment: What do you mean with moving/renaming files? Should they be in different folders or catalogued according their IMDB categorie

Comment: sorry my question was definitively too vague... see my second update

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've not used it myself, but heard good things about [Ant Movie Catalog](http://www.antp.be/software/moviecatalog) (*yes, it's a silly title*). It seems to satisfy all your demands thought - free & open source.

*(more screenshots at the page linked)*

[image]

Comment: isn't AMC the American Movie Channel or some such?  maybe they were looking to cause an acronym collision...

Comment: @~quack - wouldn't know: don't watch movies, and, I'm european ;-)

Comment: "Ant" is just the nickname of the programmer (probably from Antoine: http://www.antp.be/perso). All his programs contain "Ant", like Ant Renamer (great renaming tool).

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, but the end of the bounty is coming...

Answer (score 11):

The solution I use is put all the movie files into a single folder, and point [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/) (formely XBMC) to that folder. By default, Kodi does a pretty good job of getting movie meta-data just from having the title in the filename.

[image: XBMC screenshot]

Comment: +1, I've tested quite a few suggestions from the other answers and XBMC is undoubtedly the one-size-fits-all solution, does everything the OP asked, too bad it's *a bit* heavyweight and requires some configuration. Oh, the mouse movements are also quite annoying.

Answer (score 4):

**[MBase](http://www.quadware.com/)** allows you to manage your movies in an easy and comfortable way. With the help of an online database you just need to enter the title and MBase will fill out the fields with the appropriate data on its own. Covers and also even the actors (their birthdays and photos too) are automatically added.

- Free of charge with no Spyware
- Data for movies and actors off the Internet
- Loan Management to keep track of lent movies
- Statistics to analyze collection
- Wikipedia directly integrated
- VirtualFlip to browse through collection

[image]

*MBase is freeware and portable.*

Comment: very nice. i like the possibility to export the database into several formats, like html, xml, csv, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**[Double Feature](http://doublefeature.codeplex.com/)** is a simple movie organizer for Windows, designed for small and medium-sized collections.

**Features-**

Clean and simple interface: Forget about menus, toolbars and other rare buttons. Double Feature let you find everything you need at first sight.

Automatic info: Don't worry to add the movie info, Double Feature gets automatically the information after adding the file. Also, Double Feature offers info about the movies with similar title.

Search: The text box on the right lets you find movies you've added. Just type the name (or part) of the movie(s) you want to watch and voilà.

Lists and smartlists: You can organize your movies using lists, simply by dragging the film to the list. You can organize and store movies along at a smartlist.

[image]

Comment: +1, Pretty, pretty nice! It's very lightweight and dead simple to use. The only problem is I can't figure out how to download cover images. Other than that (and the fact that it doesn't organize TV shows) it's the perfect XBMC replacement.

Answer (score 3):

http://lifehacker.com/5466717/data-crow-is-a-cross+platform-manager-of-all-your-media

Windows/Mac/Linux (Java): [**Data Crow**](http://www.datacrow.net/) doesn't just catalog your movies with IMDB look-ups, organize your MP3s and CDs with discographies, or handle pictures. It handles all three, plus contacts, software, books, and much more, and runs on any system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MeD's movie manager fits most of these requirements.

> MeD's Movie Manager is a simple to
>   use, yet customizable, movie manager.
>   Info is automatically retrieved from
>   IMDb and tv.com. Technical info can
>   also be retrieved from media files
>   like AVI, OGM, MPEG and DVD (ifo).
>   It's written in Java and should
>   therefore run on most desktop systems
>   supporting Java.
>
> MeD's Movie Manager is a free software
>   distributed under the GPLv2 or later
>   license, you may download binaries and
>   source code for no cost at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For all my movies organization needs I just use http://mymoviescollection.net/

The service is great and you can play around with several settings that we'll make it be perfect for your needs, such as Movie location (like a folder or a shelf), format (such as DVD or digital copy), loaned or not, etc...

It now also let's you manage which TV Shows seasons and episodes you already own (downloaded) and seen or not.

There's also a mobile version that works like a charm on the iPhone, Android and Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want to organize movies that are already tagged, or if you want to be able to tag the movies (so that they show up correctly in media players like the Apple TV).  But if you want the latter, you should check out [MetaX for Windows](http://www.danhinsley.com/metax/metax.html) as it makes tagging your movies extremely simple.

It goes out to multiples sources (Amazon, tagChimp, tmdb, tvdb, ...) to get information about the movie and then writes the tags so they display perfectly on the Apple TV, or other media players.

There is also a companion product MovieLibrary, which is a simple [Movie Manager](http://www.danhinsley.com/movielibrary/movielibrary.html).  MetaX is $9.95 and MovieLibrary is free.  Full disclosure, I wrote both products.

Anyway, for tagging mp4 files (and their variants), it doesn't get any easier than MetaX.

Comment: Promoting your own product is fine if you disclose any affiliation, but please don't spam this site – if you want to contribute, please also try to keep your answers more diverse. Thank you and welcome to Super User!

Comment: Please make your disclosure more evident. A note after both links that's not clearly related is sufficient, but not very good.